# How to make the text selectable inside IonItem when there is a Button inside with Ionic

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have an `IonItem` with an `IonButton` and `IonLabel` inside. I want to copy the text from `IonLabel` so I tried putting `user-select: text;` on the `IonLabel` but it only works if there is no button inside the `IonItem`.

Is there any way to make the text selectable inside `IonItem` without moving the `IonButton` outside of the `IonItem`?

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-react-starter-xhtvmz?file=pages%2FHome.js)

```
<IonItem>
  <IonLabel style={{ userSelect: "text" }} slot="start">
    Cant select this text even with user-select: text;
  </IonLabel>
  <IonButton onClick={() => console.log("Hello")}>
    Random button
  </IonButton>
</IonItem>
<IonItem>
  <IonLabel style={{ userSelect: "text" }}>
    I can select this because there is no random button inside my IonItem
  </IonLabel>
</IonItem>
```

Comment: Check this Clipboard Plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/clipboard Pass your text on click event to your plugin and it will get copied.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using cordova.

Comment: This Plugin will work with Capacitor. Check Documentations.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I'm not using Ionic Native, I'm only using the components,  I have a custom native WebView app but I also need this working inside my React web app on Desktop.

Comment: Ok. Looks like its an issue with `IonButton` using Button inside IonItem causing this issue.